# Привязка функции к кнопке

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть родительский элемент MainMenu, у него есть элемент Buttons с кнопками. К элементу MainMenu привязан одноимённый скрипт MainMenu с функциями. Я пытаюсь привязать функции к нажатию кнопок, но функции не появляются в списке.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void StartGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }

    public void ExitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Выбираю скрипт в списке, но методов нет, подскажите пожалуйста что не так, только начал пробовать делать игру

[image: Привязка функции к кнопке]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В блок нужно привязать не сам скрипт, а `GameObject`, который на сцене с этим скриптом.

Answer (score 0):

Кинь свой скрипт на какой-нибудь объект, канвас например. И потом уже этот канвас перекинь в окно кнопки. Затем вместо noFunction увидишь свой скрипт

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).